# What is the $R$-symmetry group for ${\cal N}=6$ supergravity in $D=4$ dimensions?

Tags: symmetry, group-theory, supersymmetry, spacetime-dimensions, supergravity

What is the $R$-symmetry group for ${\cal N}=6$ supergravity in $D=4$ dimensions?

Answer (score 2):

In $D=4$ the [$R$-symmetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-symmetry) group is $U({\cal N})$, cf. Ref. 1, which also lists $R$-symmetry groups in other spacetime dimensions $D$.

References:

1. D.Z. Freedman & A. Van Proeyen, *SUGRA,* 2012; Table 12.1 p. 240.

Comment: I did found the table but i was confused for the case of $\mathcal{N}=2$, D=4, the R-symmetry group is $SU(2) \times U(1)$, and for $\mathcal{N}=4$, D=4, it is $SU(4)$, thus is it correct to assume that for $\mathcal{N}=6$, it is $SU(6)$?

Comment: Is this taken from a reference? Which page?

Comment: yes, the case of $\mathcal{N}=2$ is mentioned in Ref. 1 to be $SU(2) \times U(1)$, but this relationship is $U(2)$ as explained in Ref 2. Then for $\mathcal{N}=4$ it is $SU(4)$ from Ref. 3. $\mathcal{N}=8$ is $SU(8)$ from ref. 4, and for cases $\mathcal{N}=2, 4, 8$ there is a summary from Lect notes in Ref.5 .

Comment: References  Ref.1 C. Santoli, Solutions of $\mathcal{N}=2$ gauged supergarvity in 4,5 and 6 dimensions, 2017, table 1.1 p3    Ref.2 H. Erbin, Black holes in $\mathcal{N}=2$ sugra, 2015, sect1.4, eq (1.4.2) p7      Ref.3 M. Bertolini, lecture notes, Lecture 6, 6.2 pg 6 https://people.sissa.it/~bertmat/lect6.pdf    Ref.4 B. de Wit, Supergravity, 2002, table 12 p.45,    Ref.5  V. Kaplunovsky, Lecture Notes, http://bolvan.ph.utexas.edu/~vadim/Classes/01f/396T/table.pdf

Answer (score 2):

This is an old post, but I would like to clarify this for others who, like me, stumble upon this question now. As Qmechanic noted, the $R$-symmetry group in $D = 4$ is $U(\mathcal{N})$, which is Table 12.1 on page 240 of Ref. [1]. However, in supergravity theories, the kinetic terms for the scalars are non-trivial and determine the scalar manifold (see section 12.5 of Ref. [1]). Scalar manifolds of all supergravities with more than 8 real-component supersymmetries are symmetric spaces, *i.e.* they are spaces $G/H$, with $G$ non-compact (the isometry group) and $H$ its maximal compact subgroup (the isotropy group). An overview of the scalar manifolds for various supergravity theories is given in Table 12.3, page 250 of Ref. [1]. Ash's comment on $\mathcal{N} = 8, D = 4$ supergravity actually refers to the isotropy group being $\text{SU}(8)$, as given in that table, probably explaining the confusion. The $R$-symmetry group is always a factor of the isotropy group.

References:

1. D.Z. Freedman & A. Van Proeyen, *Supergravity*, 2012